# How to make Mocha display correct line numbers in source files if a test fails?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I'm using Mocha for my NodeJS tests, and when a test fails due to an Error thrown by my source code (for example "`TypeError: Cannot read property 'prop' of null`"), the line numbers in the displayed stacktrace are wrong (they don't match with the original source file, but are far bigger).

```
  1) MyApp should do something:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'prop' of null
      at MyApp.<anonymous> (/path/to/my-project/lib/my-project.js:515:93)
      at MyApp.build (/path/to/my-project/lib/my-project.js:774:16)
      at Context.<anonymous> (/path/to/my-project/test/test.js:62:67)
      at Test.Runnable.run (/path/to/my-project/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:216:15)
      at Runner.runTest (/path/to/my-project/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:373:10)
      at /path/to/my-project/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:451:12
      at next (/path/to/my-project/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:298:14)
      at /path/to/my-project/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:308:7
      at next (/path/to/my-project/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:246:23)
      at Object._onImmediate (/path/to/my-project/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:275:5)
      at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:330:15)
```

(Here `my-project.js` only has 279 lines !)

Is there a way to tell Mocha to display them correctly?

Comment: Have you managed to fix this? I am still having the same issue even with latest node/mocha versions.

Comment: No sorry, I still have this error...

Answer (score 18):

This happens when the code is instrumented by a coverage tool (e.g. `blanket`, `istanbul`, etc). Double-check to make sure you aren't loading it in your normal tests by mistake.