# Debugging mocha test cases in WebStorm has incorrect line numbers

Tags: node.js, debugging, coffeescript, webstorm

I'm having trouble getting WebStorm to set breakpoints and step through my coffeescript test cases in the debugger, as it appears the IDE is using line numbers from the generated .js file rather than the original .coffee file. For example, when I set a breakpoint in a .coffee file, the debugger may break in near it but at a non-code line.

This is a node application, the test cases for which are written in coffeescript and run with mocha.

The test cases run fine both from the command line and from the IDE. And if an error is encountered in either scenario, the line numbers in the reported stack trace show the correct coffeescript line numbers.

```
ReferenceError: bad_thing is not defined
  at Context.<anonymous> (C:\[project]\test\e2e\basic.test.coffee:22:5) # This is the correct line number in the coffeescript
  at Hook.Runnable.run (C:\...\mocha\lib\runnable.js:218:15)
  at next (C:\...\mocha\lib\runner.js:259:10)
  at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\...\mocha\lib\runner.js:276:5)
  at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:358:17)
```

I have WebStorm set up for automatic transpiling, and it generates output .js and .map files automatically. I am running the tests in the IDE from a "Mocha" debug configuration.

Any ideas?

I'm on Windows with:
WebStorm 10.0.0
Node 0.12.2
CoffeeScript 1.9.3
Mocha 2.1.0

Comment: Interesting that stack traces are correct. That suggests that the issue lies with the IDE and not with Node or Mocha. See if you need to explicitly configure WS with your source maps, and consider contacting JetBrains support.

Comment: I've got the same problem without using WebStorm: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25770946/535203